# Get the Max Value in MySQL in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my Query in Laravel

```
$salename = DB::table('home_sc')->where('OrderNo', $orderno)->pluck('salesconfirmation');
```

Here i am using pluck, where it will get the salesconfirmation with the $orderno.

But how can i get the salesconfirmation for the max $orderno

**Update:** OrderNo is not Unique or an Auto Increment, the table however, has another field named ID, this is the field for which I need to retrieve to max value of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `OrderNo` is an incremental value, you could do this:

```
DB::table('home_sc')->orderBy('ID', 'DESC')->where('OrderNo', $orderno)
    ->take(1)->pluck('salesconfirmation');
```

Also, just a sidenote, but it may be worth considering a change to the database structure, as you've got three naming conventions in this query alone.

Comment: Ah, sorry i have just updated the question, that it has another field called ID, where is need the salesconfirmation for the max id, and it should also match the orderno

Comment: @BizDev I've modified my answer to match.

Comment: I edited some of the grammar in your update as well just to make it easily readable by others :)

Comment: Thanks, i will follow the same